# How auto generate document number

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

In my application i have few documents types `Inovice`, `Order` , `Shipping`. All this types need to have own prefix in database with number of document. Somthing like `ID` auto increment but not that.

When i create order i need to auto generate order number like `SO-000001` and next time when i create again new order must be `SO-000001`. The some for Inovice and Shipping documents. This is not auto increment. How to to create this? Does i must create trigger or i need that to do via code in my app?

[image]

Comment: If you need this it is going to be tricky. Are you ready to rollup your sleeves?

Comment: I used this article once to auto-increment with letters... hope it helps! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680122/how-to-auto-increment-id-numbers-with-letters-and-numbers

Comment: You could use my Intention Lock code here to get your incrementor first http://stackoverflow.com/a/38079598 then prefix it, and do the insert

Comment: I wouldn't do this in SQL simply code the order number generation code in C#

Comment: Since order must not change according to the post (must be "SO-000001") I don't see any problem implementing such code... Can you please clarify? Possibly [edit] as you may have stated your requirements worng (and forgo to show either payment method or your research/attempt to solve it)